# Integrating function of optical pulse to calculate average peak power

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

In a lecture on optical communications, we are given a function that represents the shape of an optical pulse. The goal is to integrate it in order to obtain the average pulse power.

$$ A(z=0,t) = \sqrt{2P_P}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi t}{T_b}\right)\right) $$

I guess the variables $P_P$ and $T_b$ can be seen as constant here.
The task gives the hint:

$$P_{avg}=\frac{1}{T_b}\int_{0}^{T_b}|A(z=0,t)|^2 \,{\rm d}t$$

and that we should use trigonometric identities to simplify the $cos^2$ term. The function itself is implementet in MATLAB but they want us to give an analytic answer to the problem.
I don't know how to integrate a nested cosine function and would be happy about any help from you guys.
Thank you

Comment: Looking at the structure of the integral, I think Bessel functions can help.

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately i am not familiar with Bessel functions, but i will try to take a look at it. If you have any quick tip to make my journey easier i would be happy about anything. Thank you ;)